# Chrome extension to convert text to 'Sentence case.'

Tags: osx, windows-7, chrome, text-processing

I am looking for a Chrome extension that can, with a keyboard shortcut, convert text to Sentence case and vice versa.

For example:

> .THIS IS A SAMPLE TEXT

should be converted to

> .This is a sample text

Requirements:

- Keeps letter after `.` as a capital (for a sentence)
- Keyboard shortcut
- Works in website textboxes/textareas etc.
- Works on Chrome in Windows 7 and OSX 10.6.8

NOTE: I am not looking for this to convert the text in the clipboard. I am looking for a solution that works with the ***selected text inside a textbox/textarea in a website***.

Comment: Are you wanting that for text you copy out of browser or for text displayed in the browser?

Comment: Also it sounds to me that you want *Sentence Case* rather than strictly speaking *lower case* - not that it matters a lot but they are **slightly different**.

Comment: @NickWilde Ahhh... OK, I didn't know the term 'Sentence case' was actually real!

Comment: @NickWilde And, for text selected in the browser, that's it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on Franck's AutoHotKey answer, mostly from [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7516/chrome-extension-to-convert-text-to-sentence-case), is this script:

```
#d:: ConvertSentence()

ConvertSentence()
{
    clipSave := Clipboard
    Clipboard = ; Empty the clipboard so that ClipWait has something to detect
    SendInput, ^c ;copies selected text
    ClipWait
    StringReplace, Clipboard, Clipboard, `r`n, `n, All ;Fix for SendInput sending Windows linebreaks 
    StringLower, Clipboard, Clipboard ;Convert case
    Clipboard := RegExReplace(Clipboard, "(((^|([.!?]+\s+))[a-z])| i | i')", "$u1")
    Len:= Strlen(Clipboard) ;Set number of characters
    Send %Clipboard% ;Send new string
    Send +{left %Len%} ;Re-select text
    VarSetCapacity(OutputText, 0) ;free memory
    Clipboard := clipSave ;Restore previous clipboard
}
```

When you press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, the selected text will be converted to Sentence case.

Unfortunately AutoHotKey is only for Windows, so this won't work on Chrome on *all* platforms!

Comment: it works by copying the selected text, converting the copied text, pasting the converted text, and clearing the clipboard afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

A [script](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/24431-convert-text-uppercase-lowercase-capitalized-or-inverted/) to do it with [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) (scripting language for desktop automation on Windows), in case it's ok not to be browser only:

```
CTL+ALT+k - Sentence case (what you asked for)
CTL+L - convert to lowercase
CTL+U - convert to uppercase
CTL+K - invert the case (e.g. "The Big Dog" becomes "tHE bIG dOG")
SHIFT+CTL+K - convert to capitalized (e.g. "the big dog" becomes "The Big Dog")
SHIFT+CTL+U - convert to sentence case
```

Code:

```
!^k::                                           ; Sentence case
StringLower, Clipboard, Clipboard
Clipboard := RegExReplace(Clipboard, "((?:^|[.!?]\s+)[a-z])", "$u1")
Send %Clipboard%
RETURN

^u::                                                                 ; Convert text to upper
 StringUpper Clipboard, Clipboard
 Send %Clipboard%
RETURN

^l::                                                                 ; Convert text to lower
 StringLower Clipboard, Clipboard
 Send %Clipboard%
RETURN

+^k::                                                                ; Convert text to capitalized
 StringUpper Clipboard, Clipboard, T
 Send %Clipboard%
RETURN

^k::                                                                 ; Convert text to inverted
 Lab_Invert_Char_Out:= ""
 Loop % Strlen(Clipboard) {
    Lab_Invert_Char:= Substr(Clipboard, A_Index, 1)
    if Lab_Invert_Char is upper
       Lab_Invert_Char_Out:= Lab_Invert_Char_Out Chr(Asc(Lab_Invert_Char) + 32)
    else if Lab_Invert_Char is lower
       Lab_Invert_Char_Out:= Lab_Invert_Char_Out Chr(Asc(Lab_Invert_Char) - 32)
    else
       Lab_Invert_Char_Out:= Lab_Invert_Char_Out Lab_Invert_Char
 }
 Send %Lab_Invert_Char_Out%
RETURN
```

Example:

- `dvfv dKMLM sdf. sdf SDFKLMSF sdf.` -> `Dvfv dkmlm sdf. Sdf sdfklmsf sdf.`

Comment: Does this convert the clipboard text? I didn't mean that, sorry. I want to have a way to convert the text inside a textbox/textfield on a website...

Comment: @shub In this case adding a few more commands in the AHK script should do the trick. http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm